# Wordpress - Confirmation required on users email change

Tags: php, wordpress

This kind of issue was already discussed [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41730/confirmation-required-on-email-change), but the question is 10 yo and none of the answers work, obviously.

Basically, Wordpress already have this written in /wp-includes/user.php for the function, which is send_confirmation_on_profile_email(), but for some reason it's not an "option" in the settings, or am I missing something?

As far as I know, the confirmation sent to change the profile email is an 'admin-only' thing.
Is there any way to make it work for users too? I'm using Wordpress update 6

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you get a quicker response on: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I already replied to that very same question, but still no feedback. will try to add a completely new one. I often ask here because community seems to be more active